# LINQPad System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when connection

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, linqpad

When connecting to a SQL database LINQPad is trowing a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. The connection to the DB server is ok, other DBs on the server is not resulting in this error.

Error:

> startIndex connot be larger then length of string. Parameter name:
>   startIndex.

SQL Server 2008

Also: There isn`t any issues connecting with SSMS

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be fixed as of the 5.28.02 beta.

Comment: Tested on 5.28.03 beta - Without success.